# Searching a string for a substring using charAt

Tags: java, string, search, charat

CS student here. As usual I'm puzzled. My task is to use only .charAt() and .length() to search a string for a substring (both provided by the user). What it ought to return is the begin index of the substring in the string (or -1 if it isn't present at all). Frankly, I'm not sure where to begin. I attempted doing something like the following:

```
for (int i=0;i<string.length();i++)
    if (string.charAt(i) == substring.charAt(i))
```

If that was true then I wanted to do something like compare the next two characters in the respective strings. Am I way off base here? Any advice on how to get off the ground?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: whats in string? whats in substring?

Comment: I don't know. The user will provide the contents of those.

Comment: I think you have the right idea. You want to iterate through the given string, and compare the character you are at with the first character of the substring. If you find it, check for the rest of the substring.

Comment: the code should be optimized substring.length() >= string.length()

Comment: You will need a double loop (a loop nested inside another loop).

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need a nested for loop if you're only allowed to use `charAt` and `length` methods.  In the interest of not ruining the exercise for you, I'll do my best to get you started without doing it for you.

```
for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < substring.length(); j++)
```

What we have here is saying for each index of the string, iterate through all of the characters of the substring and do something.  Obviously you're going to have to compare the characters in some way.  If you make it through the entire substring and the characters match, you'll want to return the count of the outter loop because that's where the substring started.

If you make it through the entire nested loop and haven't returned an index of where the substring is, you'll want to return -1.  You'll need an `if` statement in there to provide that logic.  Comment if you need help!

Answer (score 1):

If you're just expected to do a naive solution, all you need to do is set up two loops.  One for loop to iterate through the positions of your string, and an inner while loop which can be used to iterate through your query and main string if you match the beginning character of your substring with a character in your string.  All you need to do is check to make sure that you don't go outside of the main string, which can be done with proper for loop indexing.  In the inner while loop, you can use a combination of the counter for the outer loop and the counter for the inner loop to make the necessary comparisons.

I didn't include code, since this is a homework assignment, but you should be fine from here.

Answer (score 1):

Without testing:

```
private static final int indexOf(String string, String substring) {
    outerloop: for (int i = 0; i < string.length() - substring.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < substring.length(); j++) {
            if (substring.charAt(j) != string.charAt(i + j)) {
                continue outerloop;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this could work, i cant test it right now, but i think its not a bad idea.

```
   for (int i=0;i<string.length();i++){
                if (string.charAt(i) == substring.charAt(i)){
                      int j = i+1;
                      int l =0;
                      while (l<substring.lenght && string.charAt(j) == substring.charAt(l)){
                               j++;i++;
                      } if (l=substring.lenght){
                             return i;
                      }
                 }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice approach @rolfl. 
Adding a small contribution to your solution:
there is a small bug when string is equal to substring. It will never get in the outerloop and we could have string="cat" and substring="cat" so indexOf should be 0.
Modifying the outloop should work: `i < s1.length() - (substring.length()-1)`

```
  @Test
  public void test_firstSubstring(){
    String s = "cat";
    String p = "cat";

    int actual = findFirstSubstring(s,p);
    assertEquals(0,actual);
  }

public static int findFirstSubstring(String s1, String substring){
    if(s1.isEmpty() || substring.isEmpty() || substring.length() > s1.length()){ 
        return -1;
    }

    outloop: for (int i = 0; i < s1.length() - (substring.length()-1) ; i++){
        for (int j=0; j < substring.length(); j++){
                if (s1.charAt(i+j) != substring.charAt(j)) {
                    continue outloop;
                }
            }
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
  }
```

Comment: This should be a comment on @rolfl's answer.

Comment: ah sorry, I'm pretty new with this page.